# How do you skip list numbers in a rich text editor?

Tags: 2013, richhtmlfield

Refer to the image below. How do you skip numbers in a list after an image is inserted? (The next list number should be 2, not 1).

[image]

Comment: It probably mangled the HTML, you can try editing the HTML and removing the bad UL.

Comment: I was hoping there was an OOTB way. Guess I'll just have to edit the source. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is supported, the rich text editor is fairly limited. CSS supports this so it should technically be possible. If it's an option, I'd actually look into using a different text editor like tinyMCE, they work far better for me.